# Change text color based on state or click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im having problem changing text color based on either the count is increasing or decreasing while also having the ability to change color through click event, how do I solve this. Sorry Im new to react.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const increase = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const decrease = () => setCount(count - 1);
  const [prevCount, setPrevCount] = useState(count);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('yellow')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count > prevCount) {
      setPrevCount(count - 1);
    }
  }, [count])

 function handleColorChange() {
      const nextColor = color ==='green'? "red" : "green"
      setColor(nextColor)
 }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(prevCount)}
      <button  onClick={increase}>
         increase
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleColorChange}>
         toggle color
      </button>
      <button disabled={count <= 0} onClick={decrease}>
         decrease
      </button>
      <br/>
      <p style={{color, fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold"}}>{count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: so at first you have `yellow`, then `green`, then `red` etc.... try this `<button onClick={() => setColor(color ==='green'? "red" : "green")}>

Comment: But I think your code'd work

Comment: You can call `handleColorChange` function from `increase` or `decrease` function.

Comment: Sorry im bad at explaining but i will try , i want to be able to click on a "toggle color" button to change color between "green" or "red" while also having the ability to change my color through the button "increase" or "decrease" , if my count > prevcount I want my text "count" to be green else I want it to be red; the first render of "count" text is yellow. I tried Dominik Matis answer but it only work that/one way not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation, why don't you just configure the `increase` function to set the color to green, and the `decrease` to red?

```
  const increase = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setColor("green");
  };
  const decrease = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
    setColor("red");
  };
```